# How can I fix this simple scoping error?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, scope

Having some issues with scoping. I am trying to write a program using a loop that takes 10 values representing exam grades (between 0 and 100) from the keyboard and outputs the minimum value, maximum value and average value of all the values entered. My program cannot accept values less than 0 or greater than 100.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ExamBookClient
{
   public static void main( String[] args)
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       int MAX = 100;
       int MIN = 0;
       int[] grades = new int[10];


       System.out.println("Please enter the grades into the gradebook.");
       if(scan.hasNextInt())
       {
         for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
          {
             if( x>MIN && x<MAX)
             {
             int x = scan.nextInt();
             grades[i] = x;
          }
       }
    }  
       System.out.print("The grades are " + grades.length);
   }
 }
```

My compiler error is that I cannot fix the scoping error:

```
    ExamBookClient.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
             if( x>MIN && x<MAX)
                 ^
  symbol:   variable x
  location: class ExamBookClient
ExamBookClient.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
             if( x>MIN && x<MAX)
                          ^
```

Comment: Don't use x before it's in scope. Declare it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the scoping problem, move the declaration/initialization of `x` to a point before its first use:

```
int x = scan.nextInt();
if( x>MIN && x<MAX ) {
    grades[i] = x;
}
```

There are several problems with your code:

- `if(scan.hasNextInt())` will be executed only before the first read of the `int`; you should change your code to check for next int on each iteration of the loop
- You need to add variables for the current `min`, `max`, and `total`
- You do not need to store the values in the array, because the three scalars are enough to compute all three outputs required of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Move x on top of the if.

```
if(scan.hasNextInt())
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
      {
         int x = scan.nextInt();
         if( x>MIN && x<MAX)
         {

         grades[i] = x;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `x` inside the `if` clause. So when your program reaches the `if`, `x` won't be defined. Try this:

```
int x = scan.nextInt(); // OUTSIDE THE IF
if( x > MIN && x < MAX)
{        
    grades[i] = x;
}
```